# Do app updates wipe data in sqlite?

Tags: objective-c, database, swift, sqlite

I'm storing everything in sqlite and add, update and edit them quite often in the app. It all must never be deleted and I wonder if app updates could ever wipe data stored in sqlite.

**Edit**

```
-(void)createTables{
 FMDatabase *db = [self openDatabase]; if(db == nil) return;

NSError *err;
[db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gameTable (idx INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, item0 TEXT DEFAULT'0', item1 TEXT DEFAULT'0', item2 TEXT DEFAULT'0', item3 TEXT DEFAULT'0', item4 TEXT DEFAULT'0')" withErrorAndBindings:&err];
NSLog(@"err:%@", err);
[db close];  }
```

Comment: Data stored in sandbox will persist even the app is updated unless you wipe out the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store SQlite Database in Application's Document Directory. (You Should Store it there).

It will never wipe out until you uninstall the app.

If you have update your app it will remain same. And if you have any update related to database you have to handle it.

E.g : You add a new column in your data table then you have to handle it. You can find solutions on this topic in bundle of related SO threads.

Comment: Ahh thank you. About Document Directory, what do you mean by that? Isn't everything in sqlite just saved in App's Document Directory by default? Do I have to manually do something or double check in case..?

Comment: Posted. Btw I'm using FMDB.

Comment: Okay. if you are not giving any specific paths, Its in Documents Directory. It will never wipe out.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Just double checking. This is what I get when called createTables. path: /Users/Hyunsik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CAF39391-D067-4F15-8F7C-68DDFF823272/data/Containers/Data/Application/B04A6677-F381-413B-8DAE-6CB7E4A79E3E/Documents/